# Height stutters when changing its value with a user gesture

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to build a bottom sheet UI just like the one in Apple Maps app. Usually, this is accomplished by placing the bottom sheet view outside of the visible area of the phone. However, because I'm also using a tab bar, doing this is not ideal, as it messes up the tab bar's transparency.

What I'm trying to do instead is to change the height of the bottom sheet content on a drag event by the user. Here is a reduced example with just that:

```swift
struct AnimationView2: View {
    
    @State private var translation: CGFloat = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            
            Spacer()
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                .fill(Color.green)
                .frame(height: self.height())
                .padding()
                .gesture(self.gesture())
        }
        
    }
    
    private func height() -> CGFloat {
        return 100 + abs(self.translation)
    }
    
    private func gesture() -> some Gesture {
        DragGesture()
            .onChanged { action in
                self.translation = action.translation.height
            }
    }
}
```

However, the previous example has two problems:

- **Movement is not consistent** with your finger's position. If you move the green rectangle too fast, instead of following your finger, it's left behind.
- The **movement animation is not fluid**, it stutters.

Here is an example of what I'm talking about. Maybe a GIF is not the best option to show how an animation stutters, but I think it's more or less visible:

[image: Gif of the problem]

Interestingly enough, using the exact same code but doing the movement animation with the offset property seems to work flawlessly:

```swift
struct AnimationView2: View {
    
    @State private var translation: CGFloat = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            
            Spacer()
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                .fill(Color.green)
                .frame(height: 100)
                .padding()
                .offset(y: self.translation)
                .gesture(self.gesture())
        }
        
    }
    
    private func gesture() -> some Gesture {
        DragGesture()
            .onChanged { action in
                self.translation = action.translation.height
            }
    }
}
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: The reason why it is happening is likely because: When you perform the drag gesture, the view height is changing. This will in turn change the translation, and why you get odd looking results. Using `.offset` might be a better choice, using full height, and then using `.clipped()` or `.clipShape()`. You also get similar odd behaviour when using `.offset` after `.gesture`, instead of before.

Comment: @George_E Unfortunately I can't use the bottom sheet's full height because there is a tab bar and then its transparency would be affected by the part of the sheet displayed underneath it. Is there any other way?

Comment: That's why I think clipping it might work. Then you can cut off the bottom part of the view

Comment: @George_E I'm trying to play around with `.clipped()` and `.clipShape()` but the former only clips the content overflowing the view and the latter receives a figure parameter but you can't set that figure's frame height so it ends up behaving like `.clipped()`. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how to achieve this. I used [`.clipped()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/clipped(antialiased:)) on a parent view, to restrict the size of the inside content so it doesn't go below the `TabView`.

Minimal example code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var selection: Int = 1
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selection) {
            AnimationView2()
                .tabItem {
                    Label("1", systemImage: "1.circle")
                }
                .tag(1)
            
            Text("Other view")
                .tabItem {
                    Label("2", systemImage: "2.circle")
                }
                .tag(2)
        }
    }
}



struct AnimationView2: View {
    
    @State private var offset: CGFloat = 0
    
    private var height: CGFloat {
        offset + 100 // Indicator you grab?
    }
    private var dragGesture: some Gesture {
        DragGesture()
            .onChanged { drag in
                offset = -drag.translation.height
            }
            .onEnded { drag in
                offset = 0
            }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                .fill(Color.green)
                .frame(height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)
                .offset(y: geo.size.height - height)
                .gesture(dragGesture)
                .animation(.easeOut)
        }
        .clipped()
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: GIF showing drawer working]

Comment: Thank you a lot @George_E. I've been struggling with this for a while. I appreciate your help a lot!

Comment: @Flerex No problem! I wish Apple made a native version of this because so many apps (including one I'm making right now) have to include their own custom "drawer".